# Handling EOF in user input

Tags: c, arrays, error-handling

I am writing a small program that allows a user to input the dimensions `m` and `n` of a matrix and then to fill that matrix as to her liking. To read in the numbers I use `fgets()` to read the user input as a string and then convert it via `strtol()`. I also remove the newline `fgets()` appends via `strcspn()` and do some error handling when the user types in `a`, `12a` or simply a newline `\n`. But the program gives me headache with `EOF` input via `Ctrl + D`. I read several stackoverflow threads about this and I know that one needs to type in `EOF` two times in some cases. But when I send `EOF` to my first call to `fgets()` reading in the `m`-dimension I will be forwarded to the next call to `fgets()` which reads in the `n`-dimensions and from there on it will jump to the actual array input and there it seems stuck or I goes into an infinite loop. I do currently not know the cause and I do not know how to handle `EOF` in this scenario. I would be happy if someone could give some hints. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    /* We use "m_row" and "n_col" to keep track of the matrix dimensions and "m"
     * and "n" to keep track of the size of dynamically allocated memory.  */
    unsigned long int m_row;
    unsigned long int n_col;
    unsigned long int element;

    /* Initializing at dummy value to silence compiler. */
    m_row = 1;
    n_col = 1;

    /* The largest integer that can fit into unsigned long int is a 20-digit 
     * number. */
    char save[20];
    char *ptr_save;
    printf("Enter number of rows:\n");
    if (fgets(save, sizeof(save), stdin) != NULL) {
        save[strcspn(save, "\n")] = 0;
        if (save[0] == '\0') {
            fprintf(stderr, "Wrong input\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        m_row = strtol(save, &ptr_save, 10);

        if (*ptr_save != '\0') {
            fprintf(stderr, "Wrong input\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    printf("Enter number of columns:\n");
    if (fgets(save, sizeof(save), stdin) != NULL) {
        save[strcspn(save, "\n")] = 0;
        if (save[0] == '\0') {
            fprintf(stderr, "Wrong input\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        n_col = strtol(save, &ptr_save, 10);

        if (*ptr_save != '\0') {
            fprintf(stderr, "Wrong input\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    errno = 0;
    unsigned long int **arr = calloc(m_row, sizeof(unsigned long int *));
    if (arr == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s", strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    int i;
    errno = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < m_row; i++) {
        arr[i] = calloc(m_row, sizeof(unsigned long int));
        if (arr[i] == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s", strerror(errno));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    }

    int j;
    for(i = 0; i < m_row; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < n_col; j++) {
            if (fgets(save, sizeof(save), stdin) != NULL) {
                save[strcspn(save, "\n")] = 0;
                if (save[0] == '\0') {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Wrong input\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                element = strtol(save, &ptr_save, 10);

                if (*ptr_save != '\0') {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Wrong input\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                arr[i][j] = element;
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m_row; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < n_col; j++) {
            printf("%lu\t", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong allocation size:  `m_row` vs `n_col`.  This may not be an `EOF` issue.

```
for (i = 0; i < m_row; i++) {
  // arr[i] = calloc(m_row, sizeof(unsigned long int));
  arr[i] = calloc(n_col, sizeof(unsigned long int));
}
```

Suggest initializing `m_row = 0; n_col = 0;` instead.

Code attempts to print out `arr` even if `arr` was not fully populated due to `EOF`.  Should avoid that.

If these do not fix the issue, suggest printing the `m_row` ands `n_col` prior to reading the elements to verify the matrix size is as expected.

---

Minor: Use same size integers

```
 // Rather than 
 unsigned long int m_row;
 ...
 int i;
 for(i = 0; i < m_row; i++) {

 // Use same type: recommend `size_t`
 size_t m_row;
 ...
 size_t i;
 for(i = 0; i < m_row; i++) {
```

Minor: use `strtoul()` with `unsigned long`, not `strtol()`.

Minor: "largest integer that can fit into unsigned long int is a 20-digit number" ... `char save[20];` mis-leads.  1) `pow(2,64)` takes 20 `char`, but the input needs to account for `'\n'` and `'\0'`, so should use `char save[20+2];`  2) `unsigned long int` *could* be larger than 64-bit - it must be at least 32-bit.  But this is certainly not the main problem of this post.

Comment: Thank you for all the tips! Really helpful! You were right about substituting `n_col` for `m_row`. But initializing `m_row = 0;` `n_col = 0;` woud lead `calloc()` to allocate `0` bytes. That gives a warning with `gcc` and `clang` with the right parameters set.

Comment: For learning purposes: Do you disagree with the general coding because you said that this is certainly not the main problem of this post?

Comment: @brauner `calloc(0, some_size)` is an OK thing to do.  The result may be `NULL` - which would _not_ indicate an out-of-memory.

Comment: @brauner The "not the main problem" comment refers to using `int` for an index and `unsigned long` as a limit.  This would be a problem when the index attempts to go beyond `INT_MAX`.  `INT_MAX` may be _far_ less than `ULONG_MAX`.